# Python membership of float point in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, precision

Suppose I have a list `points`of tuples of the form `(x, y)` with `x` and `y` floating point numbers. What is the most pythonic way to check if a point `(v,w)` lies close (Euclidean distance smaller than some epsilon) to some point in `points`?

(Of course the naive way would be to look with a for loop.)

I mainly want to know it for python 3, but for reference a python 2 answer is good too. Answers using open-source libraries are acceptable as well.

Comment: Do you need to identify the points it's close to or just check if there's any?

Comment: In some cases, I need the point and in other cases I do not need it.

Comment: You may find [k-d trees](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) useful.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would do it with something like this:

```python
#given GIVEN_POINT, MAX_DISTANCE and POINTS
from math import sqrt
print(list(map(lambda e: e[0],filter(lambda x: x[1]<=MAX_DISTANCE, map(lambda p: (p,sqrt((p[0]-GIVEN_POINT[0])**2+(p[1]-GIVEN_POINT[1])**2)),POINTS)))))
```

Explanation:

```python
from math import sqrt    
#given GIVEN_POINT, MAX_DISTANCE and POINTS
distance=lambda p: sqrt((p[0]-GIVEN_POINT[0])**2+(p[1]-GIVEN_POINT[1])**2)
#(the Euclidean distance from p to GIVEN_POINT where P is a point like (x,y))
point_distance = lambda p: (p,distance(p))
#map store the distance along with each point
points_n_distances = map(point_distance,POINTS)
#Now we have something like [((x1,y1),d1),((x2,y2),d2)...] in a map
close = lambda p: p[1]<=MAX_DISTANCE
closer_points = filter(close,points_n_distances)
#We do a filter based on the distances

to_point = lambda p: p[0]
filtered=map(to_point,closer_points)
#we remove the extra bit of data
#now filtered contains all the (x,y) points which are maximum of a MAX_DISTANCE far from GIVEN_POINT
```

Don't forget that `filtered` is still a `map`!

Comment: Do you know it performs speed wise?

Comment: Not really. It mostly uses the built-in `map` and `filter`, so I think it's as fast as possible, except if you have a different algorithm

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing bad about using a "naive" for loop unless you have some specific requirements (performance mainly or if you know you will have a large number of checks on the same data etc.)

a simple for loop clearly shows the intent and even weaker programmers can see what you are doing, hiding the logic behind more complex language constructs is not the right way

of course the for loop should be in a function somewhere as well as the distance calculation when you decide to change how the distance is calculated / you might want to use the distance function elsewhere in your code
plus you dont need to have the distance when you are just searching for the closest point - squared distance is easier to calculate

```
def distance_squared(point_from, point_to):
    return (point_from[0] - point_to[0]) ** 2 + (point_from[1] - point_to[1]) ** 2


def contains(points, target_point, threshold):
    threshold_squared = threshold ** 2
    for point in points:
        if distance_squared(target_point, point) <= threshold_squared:
            return True
    return False


my_points = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5.2, 6.3), (7.4, 8.5), (9.6, 10.7), (11.8, 12.9)]
print(contains(my_points,(1,1),0)) # False
print(contains(my_points,(1,1),1)) # True
print(contains(my_points,(3,4),0)) # True
```

the fact that you require the point to be a tuple of floats limits the use of external libraries like numpy or scipy

check out this codereview question https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28207/finding-the-closest-point-to-a-list-of-points to see a numpy solution - it looks cleaner and will run faster, but restricts you to use numpy arrays

Comment: Numpy arrays are fine as well, awesome link btw.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way with `numpy`, though it is not the most efficient.

```
import numpy as np

lst = [(2, 1.5), (5, 1.6), (3.2, 4), (1, 0.9), (6.2, 3), (0.999, 0.901)]

def isclose_lst(x, arrs, tolerance=0.01):
    return [i for i in arrs if np.all(np.isclose(np.array((x[0], x[1])),\
                                      np.array((i[0], i[1])), atol=tolerance))]

isclose_lst((1.001, 0.899), lst)
# [(1, 0.9), (0.999, 0.901)]
```